# Angular 2 манипуляции с DOM

Tags: dom, angular2

Доброго времени,

есть ли в Angular2 возможность манипулировать деревом DOM?

Задача:
простое выпадающее меню, при клике на пункт меню выпадает подменю, при повторном клике - исчезает.

- Пункт 1

  - Подпункт 1.1
  - Подпункт 1.2
  - Подпункт 1.3
- Пункт 2

  - Подпункт 2.1
  - Подпункт 2.2
  - Подпункт 2.3
- Пункт 3

  - Подпункт 3.1
  - Подпункт 3.2
  - Подпункт 3.3

Хотела сделать по принципу - клик -> ищем дочернее подменю -> манипулируем.
Но не могу сообразить, как это сделать в ангуляре.

Есть еще директива ngIf, наверно, в этом направлении и нужно думать, но опять же не могу сообразить, как мне задать условие отображения для каждого конкретного подменю (а не общее для всех).

Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможность есть, но пользоваться ей следует лишь в крайних случаях, т.к. практически все можно и нужно делать как и предписано идеологией фреймворка - через шаблоны, привязку данных и события, иначе непонятно зачем вам ангуляр. [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html)

Для меню достаточно простенького шаблона:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index" (click)="show[i]=!show[i]">
        {{item.name}}
        <ul [hidden]="!show[i]">
            <li *ngFor="let subitem of item.children">
                {{subitem.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Именно то, что нужно! Увы, сама не сообразила :(